# taken as vs taken for

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the two sentences is grammatically correct?

I do not want to be taken as a liar.

I do not want to be taken for a liar.

Comment: The second, *taken for* is the usual idiom. But the first would not be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-for).

Example sentences: His mother was so young that I took her for his sister. 
His sister was so old that I took her for his mother.

While "taken as" means to take something in your possession.

"I was taken as a child" means someone kidnapped me when I was a child and not that I was confused with a child.

"I was taken as a liar" would mean someone kidnapped you when you were a liar ( maybe to cleanse you :)     ).

Comment: By that logic, "I do not want to be taken for a liar" could mean that you don't think that would be a fair exchange.  "as" and "for" have multiple meanings, some of which have potentially humorous implications.